# Android distribution build is not working fine. Development build is working fine

Tags: android, titanium

I have created an app using titanium for android. Development build of app is working fine in every device. I tested the distribution build before uploading on google-play. It is giving me an error(I am showing the error in alert but it gives me only two curly braces) on a particular page. How can identify the issue. It caught in catch block but it is not giving any specific error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the issue. ***I was using a function that was declare and define after calling it.*** That breaks the flow of code. Javascript runs the code line by line.That's why it create problem. When we test the development build , it is not minifed.While distribution build is minified. ***Just check the publishing build before uploading on store. It may be some issue like this.***